# Проблема со скриптом

Tags: php, mysql

Вот смотрите:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM book WHERE name = 'Книга'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
    echo "Записи до сих пор нет!"; 
}else{ 
    echo "Такая запись уже существует!"; 
}
```

Я подключаюсь к таблице, задаю данные в SELECT id FROM book WHERE, сохраняю, заливаю на хостинг, и все равно скрипт не срабатывает. Я уже весь гугл перерыл, так и ничего не работает. ( Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @xAnonymousx укажите, о каком языке идет речь. Скрипты бывают разные. Также отформатируйте пожалуйста код, для этого есть специальная кнопка {} в редакторе

Comment: Разве не видно что это скрипт php подключения к базе mysql

Comment: @xAnonymousx речь идет о метках к вопросу. Из общей страницы с вопросами этого не видно, поскольку метка там только одна - мало о  чем говорящий "скрипт". То есть человек, которого интересует php и/или mysql и который мог бы вам помочь, этого может не увидеть и просто пройти мимо

Comment: "скритп не срабатывает" - это что, падает, выводит какое то сообщение (если да. то какое именно), просто белая страница.

Comment: @KoVadim,
Вот ошибка
 
>Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u299303977/public_html/index4.php on line 20
Òàêàÿ çàïèñü óæå ñóùåñòâóåò!

Эти символы - это кодировка, я знаю, но вот всегда один и тот же ответ выдается.

Comment: Там выводит "Такая запись уже существует!". Просто Ваш браузер решил, что там "CP1252", а на самом деле - "CP1251".

Comment: @xAnonymousx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В mysql_num_rows() попадает совсем не то, что нужно.

В случае ошибки в запросе, [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) возвращает значение FALSE. Именно об этом и говорит ошибка, что в [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) попало булево значение вместо ресурса, то есть этот самый FALSE. Проверяйте ошибки в запросе SQL или в подключении к БД, можно вызовом [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) - там в документации есть пример:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

    mysql_select_db("nonexistentdb", $link);
    echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";

    mysql_select_db("kossu", $link);
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable", $link);
    echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
?>
```

Подставьте в него свои данные и посмотрите результат.

Comment: @Alex Krass,
 Вы меня не поняли мне нужно делать сверку с базой данных, то есть в форму html вводят код, например, 12345, и если он есть в базе, то появляется окно, что в базе есть такой код, а если нет такого кода, то выводится сообщение, что нет такого кода.

Comment: Так если у вас ошибка на этапе подключения к БД, то ничего вы не сможете извлечь. Прочитайте еще раз ответ Alex Krass более внимательно!

Comment: @xAnonymousx, я Вас прекрасно понял и говорю, что варнинг выводится из-за ошибки в сверке. Скорее всего в вашей SQL строке "SELECT id FROM book WHERE name = 'Книга'" содержится какая-то ошибка. Для этого и предлагаю вызвать mysql_error и посмотреть, что там происходит. Есть еще вариант, что подключение не установилось, это тоже надо проверить через mysql_error.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем сравнивать выражение

```
mysql_num_rows($result)
```

с **0**? Если есть записи, то выражение в любом случае уже TRUE, разве нет?

Comment: query возвращает или result, или true. Без проверки на тип получается всегда true, если не было ошибок в самом запросе или в API. Проверить, если ли в результате _полезные_ данные, можно или попыткой получить их - если нет, то будет null, - или проверив количество строк полезных данных (а для бесполезных данных запрашивается affected_rows).

Comment: Ребята! Всем спасибо, дяденька @Alex Krass помог все сделать, бльшое спасибо. )

Comment: Я проверил. Если записей не находится, то это выражение и так равно 0 (т.е. false), иначе > 0 (т.е. true). Т.о., вполне жизнеспособна конструкция вида:

    if(!mysql_num_rows($result)){ 
        echo "Записи до сих пор нет!"; 
    }else{ 
        echo "Такая запись уже существует!"; 
    }

Или что-то другое имелось в виду?

Answer (score 0):

Без явного указания линка mysql_query($sql) его может и не быть.

Comment: <?php

$_REQUEST["nmag"];

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "blabla";
$dbpass = "12345";
$dbname = "bla bla";

$dbconnect = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbusername", "$dbpass") or die("Подключение не удалось " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("No connect" . mysql_error());


$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE id = '" . $_REQUEST["nmag"] . "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
die('Запрос содержит ошибку: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
echo "Zapisi net!";
}else{
echo "Takay zapisy esty!";
}

?>
Вот ответ на все мои вопросы.